# What does this d3 time format function mean?

Tags: d3.js

I know there is a specified d3 time formatting. But when I check the example shown here   `d.Year = new Date(d.Year,0,1);` the year's format is `"1996"`

Does it one of the other ways to format year as a string here, i don't quite understand it.

Also, if my time format is like"01/01/96", what is the right format to get the string here?

Comment: What is `d.Year`? Your example doesn't use the d3 time formatting functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering, the example is from here, don't quite understand the time formating http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/

Comment: Did you have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)?

Comment: Yes, i have look at this. But the example seems to use none of them.

Comment: That's right. Which is why I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a d3 date formatting function.  Its one of the basic forms of the [Javascript Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Specifically, it is using the multi-parameter form of the constructor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
```

except that all the time parameters are left as their default (0/midnight) values.  If the original value for `d.Year` is the string `"1996"`, the line

```
d.Year = new Date(d.Year,0,1);
```

creates a new Date object with year 1996 (the conversion from string to number will be automatic), month value zero (January), day value 1, and time midnight.

Comment: Thank you!! That make sense. So the way to deal with "11/10/96" is to parse it first?Or is there some specific format just in js?

Comment: I would recommend using a parsing function for a date string.  There is a `new Date(stringValue)` constructor, but browsers don't all support the same formats for the string ([more on supported string formats from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)).  It's especially important considering that "11/10/96" is an ambiguous format -- Chrome interprets that as November 10,1996 (i.e., US date syntax) when I would have interpreted it as 11 October.